# Sensors persistence approaches

Tags: android, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'd like to save sensors like accelerometer, gyroscope, etc data and I don't know what's the best approach for that using a FAST or GAME selection.
For example, I can think of saving 10 seconds of data in memory, and then making a batch insert into the database so I will not saving at a rate of 20ms to the database and block the phone, but I don't know how much time it could take a bath insert of 1000 records.
Any other approach? My goal would be that at a desired time the records in the database will be sent to a specified web service.
Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar when I kept 5000 events in memory and printed it out to the console afterwards on iPhone to do some offline research. Besides the sluggish behaviour of the iPhone console in general it worked out pretty good.

So do you really need a web service and thus a bunch of user data? (I hope the users know that big brother is watching them ;-) Well, if so you should consider using compression and send out binary data, expecially if the users are not connected to their WLAN.

Kay

Comment: What other option do you have in mind besides web service?
Was the phone working smoothly while getting the data?
Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: Keeping 5000 rows with about 20 elements in memory didn't matter at all and I didn't notice any difference in behaviour running acccelrometer with 100Hz.

Comment: Depends on what you are to. My guess was that you don't want to collect sensor data from users but want to do some statistical analysis like bias estimation, or feed some replay mode of your app when running in simulator. So you can keep them in memory and write them at once to a log file for downloading - assumed that you just want to analyse your own phone. If need huge loads of data from other users you can do it similar and then send it via email with a zipped attachment like iPhone's sensor monitor does.